# pass data to statically included fragment from fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, static, fragment

I have a fragment defined in my xml layout and I want to pass data to it from my fragmentactivity. Is that possible ? I don't want to include the fragment at run time because I am not planning to change fragments during the life of the activity.
Here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.fragments.MyProfileFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hoppiesFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.fragments.HoppiesFragment" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FragmentManager#findFragmentById` method to get fragment and pass data to some of its public methods.